# Referring to childNodes (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, dom, child-nodes

The game in this example has a variable number of players.  A score needs to be tracked for each player.  The example managed to create the HTML needed, but I'm not sure how to reference each child.  Here's the HTML:

```js
var players=prompt("Number of players?",2);

oldNode = document.getElementById("scoreHolder");

for (x=1;x<players;x++) {
  newNode = oldNode.cloneNode(true);
  document.documentElement.appendChild(newNode); 
}

var c=document.getElementById("scoreHolder").childNodes;
c[1].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
c[2].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
```

```html
<div id="scoreHolder">Player 1 score: <span id="score">0<span></div>
```

This example turns part of the first line of HTML yellow, but does nothing with the other lines.  How can I reference them so that I can update each player's score?

Comment: I want ask one question : Do you know from what index starts Array ?

Comment: @xAqweRx Player #1 is already in the DOM so it can be skipped.

Comment: I wanted to tell you, thar Array in JS starts form 0 index, not from 1 index.

Comment: @xAqweRx And I wanted to tell you that the program would not work correctly if  you started looping from 0.

Comment: Then provide more HTML code. because I can't see it.

Comment: Yes, agreed that arrays start at 0.  This isn't a typical case, though.  Player 1 is already included.  We need to add (length-1) elements.    We could start counting at 1 or we  could stop when we reach length-1.

Comment: @xAqweRx Click on the "Run code snippet" button. When it asks for the number of players, type "4" and press ok. You'll see 4 rows appear. Why do you think there is a problem?

Comment: @Juhana I'm telling that it's not correct to set manually backgorund elements with index 1 and 2 if you don't know how many of them will be added.

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
    <!-- add name attribute -->
    <div id="scoreHolder" name="scoreHolder">Player 1 score: <span id="score">0<span></div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var players=prompt("Number of players?", 2);

        oldNode = document.getElementById("scoreHolder");

        for (var x=1;x<players;x++) {
          newNode = oldNode.cloneNode(true);
          newNode.id="newId"+x; // reassign the new id
          document.documentElement.appendChild(newNode);    
        }

        // use getElementsByName
        var c=document.getElementsByName("scoreHolder");
        c[0].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
        c[1].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you. I finally see blue showing up.  I'll remember to use getelementsByName next time.  I also notice the clever thing you did with adding new ids.

Answer (score -1):

For doing this use for loop :

```
for( var i = 0; i < c.length; i++ ){
   if( i%2 == 1 )
       node[i].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
   else    
       node[i].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
}
```

---

**Update**
I've made a mistake with indexes. try updated one

---

**UPDATE 2**

You have a problem with function `document.getElementById("scoreHolder")` - it returns only **one** element, so try add class to #scoreHolder and document.getElementsByClassName and delete ID from appended elements

Comment: I tried out your code, but no blue shows up.  Thanks for trying, though!

Comment: I've made a mistake when wrote it. Try new one.

Comment: This won't work because `getElementById()` only ever retrieves one element, not an array.